Cannot delete sms draft on Samsung S23+
By mistake when forwarding an SMS I selected a thread that does not allow replies (messages from my bank). Now each time I open the messaging app there is the draft message on top of the list and there is nothing I can do to delete. I cannot find any option to delete the draft from this thread. Also when I actually open the said thread the draft text is nowhere to be seen...
I tried deleting the apps cache, but it does not help.
I tried force stopping the app. No help.
Within the thread there aren't any options related to drafts.
I know I could delete the entire thread or app data, but I do not want to lose the data from it.
Is the solution from this link (it's 7 year old) really safe in terms of not losing all SMS history?
How can delete a draft for a no-reply sender?
If not, is there anything else I can try ?

Could you mention the messaging app? Is it Samsung Message (blue speech bubble with 3 dots), Google Messages (2 overlapping blue speech bubbles), or something else?

Google Messages.
